# user input validation of int length

Tags: c#

l am writing a class assignment for a simple login program where user will input username, password and mobile number on the console. My problem is on the mobile number, l want them to input a 10 digit number and only 10, if they input less or more than 10 it must show an error. Here is my code so far:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Mobile Number:");
Console.WriteLine("**Please note Mobile Number should be 10 digits only e.g     07...");

//AVOIDS EXCEPTION     HANDLING OF ENTERING ANY TYPE THAT IS NOT AN INTEGER
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Option))    {

Console.WriteLine("***************************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid numerical value!");
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter option 1 or option 2:");
}
```

Comment: Phone numbers shouldn't be stored as `int`s...  Get the result using `Console.ReadLine()` and then simply just check the length of the string...

Comment: After checking for the string length try to convert it to an integer (while this could be enough to satisfy your requirements keep in mind that not all valid phone numbers are composed of digits)

Answer (score 0):

Read the console in string variable, count the length and check if the string is a digit.
//code

```
string mobNo = Console.ReadLine();
if(mobNo.Length == 10)
{
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(mobNo);
    if(isNum)
    //continue code
}
//return error
```